# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker in modal only working on first click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

The date picker seems to be only working on the first click and then after that it won't pop up. I am guessing it has something to do with some crossed variable or function definitions, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ridTspMBHE1iphrSobQr?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open_modal()">Edit</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="notificationInput.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">My Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="n_title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_title" value="{{selectedNotification.title}}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="n_release">Release</label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="n_release" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {

  $scope.open_modal = function(notification) {

        $scope.selectedNotification = notification;
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'notificationInput.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            scope: $scope
        });
    };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
        return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.initDate = new Date('2016-15-20');
    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

};
```

Comment: i don't see where you are adding your controllers to your angular module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using it inside modal there is scope issue. You just need to use `$parent.opened` instead `opened`.

**Modified HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="n_release" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="$parent.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wh0kSSXfoakcqw5cNAf4?p=preview)

Comment: This is working greatly. Previously I had lagging. Now there is no lagging

Comment: When I click on button, there is no issue. When I click on input box, The date picker is not opening and I am getting the following issue in console.
"Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null"

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

In html replace `is-open="opened"` by `is-open="field.opened"`

and the same in the controller, replace

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
};
```

by

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.field.opened = true;
};
```